# multiple WHERE conditions on single SQL queery

Tags: sql

I have an SQL statement that works well, but I want to modify to retrieve more records.

here is the statement:

select transactiondb.transid,transactiondb.opentime,transactiondb.openempname as empname,transactiondb.roomname as room,transactiondb.tablenumber,transactiondb.amount as oldamount,transactiondb.amount as newamount,transactiondb.znumber,0 as selected from transactiondb,trans_payment where transactiondb.transid = trans_payment.transid and **trans_payment.paymenttypeid = 1**

I need to enhance it to get **trans_payment.paymentypeid** 2, 3, 4 and so on.

Comment: Use `IN` instead of `=` for multiple `paymentypeid`.

Comment: `where column=expression or column=expression or...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try trans_payment.paymenttypeid IN (1, 2, 3, 4)